# Number of solution for $ 100 \ge x_1+x_2+x_3$

Tags: combinatorics

How many nonnegative integeres solution there are to $ 100 \ge x_1+x_2+x_3$? 
I can't determine if the answer is $\binom{102}{3}$ or $ \binom{103}{3} $.

Answer (score 1):

It's $103\choose 3$. That's the number of ways to pick three disctinct numbers $1\le y_1\le y_2\le y_3\le 103$. Each such triple $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ corresponds to a solution $x_1=y_1-1$, $x_2=y_2-y_1-1$, $x_3=y_3-y_2-1$ and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

Denote the number of solutions for $n\geq x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}$ by $s\left(n\right)$.
Then $s\left(0\right)=1$ and for $n>0$: $$s\left(n\right)=s\left(n-1\right)+\binom{n+2}{2}$$

Here $\binom{n+2}{2}$ stands for the number of solutions of $n=x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}$.

This leads to: $$s\left(n\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{k+2}{2}=\binom{n+3}{3}$$
(can easily be shown by induction)